# How to calculate profit on real estate after x years?

Tags: real-estate, calculation, profitability

If I want to calculate the "profit if sold" for a property after X years, what is this calculation based on?

One thought is it is equal to the projected sale price (based on some assumption about appreciation), minute the remaining loan balance, minus the closing costs at purchase, minus the selling fees, plus any cash flow for each year (positive or negative).

What am I missing here? Or is this getting close?

Comment: are you calculating the number to know what the return on your investment was, or are you calculating it for tax purposes? Was is property you rented out?

Comment: Forgive me for not asking the question clearly. I'm new to this stuff. I'm trying to project the calculation for a prospective investment that is rented and for which I can guess the monthly cash flow by looking at the likely rent. So to answer your question I'm trying to model what my profit would be "if sold" for a given year.  The biggerpockets rental property calculator does this but I can't reproduce it's numbers.